# How to call adapter inside dialogfragment inner class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` that opens when the application is launched the first time. The user selects a value which is then stored as a preference, then a `listview` is filled with data according to the selected value.

The problem is that my custom `DialogFragment` is an inner class, inside my MainActivity. I cannot seem to call my adapter (which loads my `listview` with data) inside **onclick**.

I have tried accessing my adapter function in the inner class but I receive a "static" reference error. At the same time, I tried embedding my adapter function inside the class, but that resulted in the same:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

I've toyed around with some hacks, but I know there is a better, standard way of doing this. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

My code is listed below.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private Cursor lines;
private MetroSleepDb db;
private ListAdapter adapter;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "METROSLEEP_PREFS";
public static int PREFS_CITY = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    boolean prefs_isset = settings.contains("DEFAULT_CITY");

    if(prefs_isset) {

        PREFS_CITY = settings.getInt("DEFAULT_CITY", 0);


    } else {

        chooseCityDialog();
        PREFS_CITY = settings.getInt("DEFAULT_CITY", 0);

    }

    Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("DEFAULT_CITY", PREFS_CITY);
    editor.commit();

}


public void setAdapters() {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preference set to: "+PREFS_CITY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    db = new MetroSleepDb(this);
    lines = db.getLines(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread
    //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            lines, 
            new String[] {"line_id"}, 
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);


    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(onAnswerClicked);

}


public String getItem(int pos) {

    Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(pos);
    String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("line_id"));
    return value;
}


private OnItemClickListener onAnswerClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String line_value = getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseStations.class);
        intent.putExtra("line", line_value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem  item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void chooseCityDialog() {

    DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogSetup();
    newFragment.setCancelable(false);
    newFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "citypref");


}


public static final class DialogSetup extends DialogFragment {
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.prompt_choose_city)
               .setCancelable(false) 
               .setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
               .setItems(R.array.Cities, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       PREFS_CITY = which;

               }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Do whatever
    }

}



@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  //editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  settings.getInt("DEFAULT_CITY", PREFS_CITY);
  editor.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried accessing my adapter function in the inner class but I
>   receive a "static" reference error. At the same time, I tried
>   embedding my adapter function inside the class, but that resulted in
>   the same:

In the `DialogFragment` you already have a reference to the `Activity` where the `Dialog` is shown which you could use to access the adapter:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      PREFS_CITY = which;
      MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
      // create a getter method in the MainActivity to access the adapter 
      // or whatever else you need
}
```